# Concordanza del verbo?

Tags: grammar, agreement

Mi chiedo se sia più corretto concordare col soggetto o con gli avverbi/aggettivi quantitativi 
Per esempio:

1) È rimasta un chilo di torta/ne è rimasta un chilo o è rimasto un chilo di torta/ne è rimasto un chilo?

2) È rimasto metà panino/ne è rimasto metà o ne è rimasta metà

3) è rimasto 3 quarti di panino/ne è rimasto 3 quarti o sono rimasti 3 quarti di panino/ne sono rimasti 3 quarti?

Ovviamemte il mio dubbio riguarda anche le medesime frasi, ma con un aggettivo.. es: tre quarti di torta è marcia/ne è marcia 3 quarti. 
metà panino è marcio/ne è marcio metà.

Non lo so, sinceramente non so darmi una spiegazione ma mi viene naturale dire " metà/la metà di quel panino è marcia/ne è marcia metà/la metà" o " 3 quarti di quel panino sono marci", così "come è rimasta meta/la metà di quel panino"
Forse perché in questo assumono un valore più sostantivale e quindi fanno da soggetto.

Mi scuso per le troppe frasi, ma vorrei capire come concodare il verbo, perché sono piuttosto confuso e vorrei delle dritte.
Ps mi scuso anche per le troppe barre ma le frasi sono tutte connesse

Comment: Mi chiedo che cosa voglia dire concordare con un avverbio...

Comment: Intendo la quantità espressa, ovvero un chilo, tre quarti ecc...

Comment: “Un chilo”, “tre quarti” etc. non sono avverbi...

Comment: Si, ma esprimono comunque una quantità. Io dico " è rimasta un chilo di torta" ma allo stesso tempo "è rimasta metà panino/" e quest'ultima non mi suona, a meno che non aggiungi la preposizione "di".

Comment: Qui mi riferivo solo al fatto che gli avverbi non c'entrano. Per il resto vedi la risposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le frasi corrette sono:
1) È rimasto / Ne è rimasto
2) È rimasta / Ne è rimasta
3) Sono rimasti / Ne sono rimasti
4) Tre quarti sono marci
5) È marcia la metà

Il verbo in queste frasi si accorda con il soggetto, qualsiasi esso sia.

Comment: Questo è vero solo in presenza dell'ausiliare *essere*. Quando l'ausiliare è *avere* le regole sono [un filo più complicate](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accordo-participio-passato).

Comment: C'è una spiegazione a tutto ciò? Io qua per esempio dico "di torta ne è RIMASTA un po'/un po' di quella torta è MARCIA" qui accordiamo il verbo col soggetto.

Comment: Non proprio: “dall'inizio dell'anno sono sbarcati più di un milione di profughi” è certamente corretto, anche se qualche parruccone potrebbe dissentire.

Comment: @egreg: Non c'entrano i “parrucconi”, e anche la categoria di “corretto” c'entra poco con la linguistica moderna, ma è innegabile che fin da Dante e Boccaccio in italiano convivono la [concordanza a senso](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza-a-senso_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) e un più rigido accordo grammaticale.

Comment: @DaG Il mio “corretto” corrisponde a quello nella risposta.

Comment: @egreg. Giusto: in effetti anche nella risposta (e nella stessa domanda) è un po' anacronistico parlare di “correttezza”.

Comment: @Benedetta: Personalmente “È rimasta metà panino” non mi suona molto bene, ma forse perché non direi “metà panino” bensì “mezzo panino”.

Comment: @DaG...Si, ma anche qui vale la famosa concordanza a senso? Rileggendo le frasi della mia domanda come ti sentirestidi correggerle. Vorrei avere delle opinioni, giusto per vedere come orientarmi

Comment: @Nakamura: Concordo con la risposta di Benedetta, a cui ho dato +1, a parte per quello che commento qui sul panino.

Comment: @DaG: ho preferito rimanere legata alle frasi proposte. Anche io direi "mezzo panino", in effetti.

Comment: @Nakamura: Non so se ho mai detto "Un po' di quella torta è marcia"… In ogni caso, qui "marcia" non è il verbo, bensì un aggettivo qualificativo. Se lo riferisci a "un po' di" è maschile, se lo riferisci a "torta" è femminile.

Comment: @Benedetta: Mi piacerebbe chiarire definitivamente i miei dubbi: 1)un po' di quella torta è marcia/marcio, ne è marcia/marcio un po' (di quella torta). 2)è rimasta/o un po' di quella torta, ne è rimasta/rimasto un po' . 3) un chilo di torta è marcia/marcio, ne è marcio/marcio un chilo (di quella torta). 4) è rimasta/o un chilo di torta, ne è rimasta/o un chilo (di torta/di quella torta). Tutte le varie concordanze sono ammesse? Lo chiedo perchè vedo varie opinioni e mi piacerebbe sapere se anche qui può valere la doppia comcordanza della quale si parlavs

Comment: @Nakamura: la concordanza "a senso" si usa, in senso stretto, quando il soggetto è collettivo (punto 2. http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza-a-senso_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/). Negli altri casi, si seguono criteri "non grammaticali" che dipendono dall'influenza del dialetto di origine, o dalle abitudini, o da "come suona" una frase (vedi, ad esempio, lo scambio sopra a proposito di metà/mezzo), ecc. A mio parere, nei nuovi esempi che proponi (e che non erano nella tua prima domanda), nei casi 3) e 4) è corretto usare "marcio" e "rimasto", senza la doppia possibilità.

Comment: @Nakamura: nel caso 1) e 2) ho dei dubbi. "Un po' di" è una quantità molto piccola, l'esempio 2) si può dire anche «È rimasta della torta» (con il partitivo), quindi per questo "mi suona" meglio «È rimasta un po' di torta». Il caso 1) è difficile da risolvere perché la frase è proprio strana, per l'uso di "marcia" e di quel tipo di quantità. Preferirei dire «Una parte della torta è rovinata/andata a male». Ma sono interessata a sentire i pareri degli altri.

Comment: @Benedetta: grazie della risposta. Sarebbe errato dire " è rimasta/c'è molta/tanta (o poca)di questa torta" oppure " molta/tanta (o poca) di questa torta è marcia"? Diciamo a me personalmente suona di più senza il "di", quindi "tanta torta è marcia" e "è rimasta tanta torta" . Ad ogni modo mi suons più pulito dire " una piccola parte/gran parte". Tu cosa ne pensi?

Comment: @Nakamura: personalmente, direi «È rimasta molta/poca torta» («È rimasta una piccola parte di torta» non è scorretto, ma nessuno lo direbbe né lo scriverebbe, penso), ma così stiamo scivolando verso un altro tipo di domanda.

Comment: @Benedetta:   Si, me ne rendo conto. da parte tua, dal momento che un opinione su ciò che chiedevo prima me l'hai data, gradirei soltanto un'analisi sulle restanti frasi del mio penultimo commento, ovvero : " è rimasta tanta /poca di questa torta", "tanta di questa torta è marcia" e "tanta/poca torta è marcia". Grazie mille per aver risposto alle mie continue domande, un po' ripetitive

Comment: @Nakamura: ti avevo risposto per come possibile.

Comment: @Benedetta: Si... lo so. Volevo solo un ultimissimo parere sulla correttezza di queste ultime 3 frasi.